# Beautiul Soup returning strange characters (chinesse)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using Python3 and BeautifulSoup v4

```
url='http://www.eurobasket2015.org/en/compID_qMRZdYCZI6EoANOrUf9le2.season_2015.roundID_9322.gameID_9323-C-1-1.html'
r=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

returns what you would expect

however

for this url, similar page but different game
    http://www.eurobasket2015.org/en/compID_qMRZdYCZI6EoANOrUf9le2.season_2015.roundID_9322.gameID_9323-D-3-1.html

the same code returns this

ℼ佄呃偙⁅瑨汭倠䉕䥌⁃ⴢ⼯㍗⽃䐯䑔䠠䵔⁌⸴㄰吠慲獮瑩潩慮⽬䔯≎∠瑨灴⼺眯睷眮⸳牯⽧剔砯瑨汭⼱呄⽄

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate using `.content`, why it is happening is because of the following meta tag, the charset is set to `UTF-16`:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16">
```

A workaround is to specify the *from_encoding* as *utf-8:*

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
```

You can also decode the bytes:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

If you print the headers, you can see `'Content-Type': 'text/html; Charset=UTF-8'`, the data is actually utf-8 encoded but the meta tag is incorrect.

If we get the content, decode it ourselves and print a slice you can see it is in fact getting decoded to *utf-16* by bs4:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.get("http://www.eurobasket2015.org/en/compID_qMRZdYCZI6EoANOrUf9le2.season_2015.roundID_9322.gameID_9323-D-3-1.html")

In [3]: print(r.content.decode("utf-16")[:10])
ℼ佄呃偙⁅瑨汭倠䉕䥌

In [4]: print(r.content.decode("utf-8")[:10])
<!DOCTYPE
```

Comment: Couldn't you have gotten the character set just by inspecting the headers? Why is there uncertainty regarding UTF-8, if I may ask?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan, yes but since the domain does not change there is no need,  I also said there was no uncertainty.